# PHP Script using session data for login, is it a security risk

Tags: php, security, authentication

im using a script from here: http://www.php-login.net

I altered it to suit my own needs but i see this part in the script:

```
// if user has an active session on the server
    elseif (!empty($_SESSION['user_name']) && ($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] == 1)) {

        $this->loginWithSessionData();      

        // checking for form submit from editing screen
        if (isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_name"])) {

            $this->editUserName();

        } elseif (isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_email"])) {

            $this->editUserEmail();

        } elseif (isset($_POST["user_edit_submit_password"])) {

            $this->editUserPassword();

        }
```

I am not too sure how session variables work since there on the server and technically they cant be altered directly however this part of the code shows it can be altered indirectly if someone messed with cookies.

```
private function loginWithSessionData() {

    $this->user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $this->user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];

    // set logged in status to true, because we just checked for this:
    // !empty($_SESSION['user_name']) && ($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] == 1)
    // when we called this method (in the constructor)
    $this->user_is_logged_in = true;        

}
```

Im not sure if its possible but if i messed with the cookies and set username=x and got lucky and set is_logged_in as 1 could that give the user access? Im sure there is a much safer method of validating a session or do cookies themselves also come with there own type of validation like checking the machine hash and that hash must also match with the hash we stored on the server? Instead of something as simple as user_logged_in should i use a random string called it iftodaywasarainyday and just comment it internally so i know what that value corresponds with my is_logged_in or does it even matter.

I will do some more reading up on the subject but i guess i took the authors word for it since the first 3 words on the page are "A simple, clean and secure" and the site does look quite good but as i was refactoring the code there is lots of todo statements which got me worried its work in progress rather than a finished script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session data is stored server-side.  The actual data isn't in the cookie at all.  The cookie is just an ID that let's the server know which session data to load.  Users cannot modify this session data unless you allow them to by writing code that does it.